# Python add method to library class

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7.4 and pillow library, and I want to add method to Image class.
I tried

```
def myFunc(self, a):
    (do something)
Image.myFunc = myFunc
im = Image.new('RGBA', (w, h), 0)
im.myFunc(a)
```

but this gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\main.py", line 755, in <module>
    TooltipRender.render()
  File "...\main.py", line 146, in render
    img.put(frame_cover, (3, 3))
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'put'
```

(not writing im = Image(~) myself might be problem?)

I cound write `myFunc(im, a)` but I want something which looks better.

Comment: Is your `~` a variable? Is there actually a definition of `myFunc()` which you just shortened? Because a function definition should start with `def function_name():`, and I don't see that colon here.

Comment: Looks a lot more understandable already. Could you also copy/paste the Error message itself? There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong.